# Evaluate expression in a string recursively

Tags: c++, string, parsing, recursion

Lets say we would like to evaluate expressions in a string. Expressions represented by `(###)` for simplicity in the example. We only count the hashtags in the example for simplicity. Expressions can be nested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string expression{ "(###(##)#(###)##)" };

int countHash(std::string::iterator stringIterator, std::string::iterator stringEnd)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (stringIterator != stringEnd)
    {
        if (*stringIterator == '#')
        {
            result += 1;
        }
        else if (*stringIterator == '(')
        {
            result += countHash(++stringIterator, stringEnd);
        }
        else if (*stringIterator == ')')
        {
            return result += countHash(++stringIterator, stringEnd);
        }
        ++stringIterator;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << countHash(expression.begin(), expression.end()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output: 51**

**Expexted output: 11**

So my problem is when I return from the recursive call the iterator is not updated. It is behind. The processing goes through parts of the string multiple times. How should I handle this?

My main goal by the way is to be able to evaluate expressions like this:

```
std::string expr = "(+1 (+22 3 25) 5 (+44 (*3 2)))";
EXPECT(106== evalExpression(expr.begin(), expr.end()));
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I updated my question based on the suggestions in the comments.

Comment: Pass the iterator by reference if you're really sure you want to do that?

Comment: how can `(+1 (+22 3 25) 5 (+44 (*3 2)))` result in `320`?

Comment: @appleapple you are right, it values 106

Comment: and your `countHash` is hardly the same thing as your target expression, as there is no coupled token `()`.

Comment: My bad, I miscalculated. Tried to update my original question based in your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string expression{ "#####-###-##" };

int countHash(std::string::iterator & stringIterator, std::string::iterator stringEnd)
{
  int result = 0;
  while (stringIterator != stringEnd)
  {
    switch (*stringIterator++)
    {
    case '#':
      result += 1;
      break;
    case '-':
      result += countHash(stringIterator, stringEnd);
      break;
    default:
      // indicate error ?
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  std::string::iterator b = expression.begin();
  std::cout << countHash(b, expression.end()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course in the current case the recursion is useless, but it will be useful to manage a sub expression (...) in evalExpression

Comment: Thanks. :) What I don't like about this is that I can't pass `expression.begin()` directly. So as a user of the function it would be very strange and unconformable for me that I can't call the function directly. Also passing iterators by reference is common practice? I could't really find anything on that?

Comment: You can use an intermediate function receiving the iterator as value and in it you call the current one receiving the reference.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the helper function and still be able to pass a string or a string begin and string end to the function? Without any character type converting or substring creation inside the function? Thank you.

Comment: For me the best way is to have an entry function receiving the begin iterator as value and to have the current function. Do not compute substrings, this is expensive and you don't need to compute the expression result. What you mean about character type converting ?

Comment: Of course you can also use index rather than iterator, but the problem will be the same, an entry function receiving begin index by value then an other using reference

Comment: You can also use stringstream initialized with the string, and read in that stream to compute the result, no iterator visible because managed inside the stream. That also allows you to use it to get int values easily

Comment: This answer could be improved considerably for other readers with a couple of sentences of explanation: *identify* the problem, *describe* the change, and *briefly explain* why it fixes the issue. Also, stringstream is a reasonable approach but a comment is not the best place for it.

Comment: @rici probably, I can also easily give an example of code using the stringstream and computing the expression, but I think is better for bencemeszaros to do it by himself, we learn much more doing rather than  looking an other guy doing :-) But may be I am wrong ?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to write the code, since future readers won't be starting with exactly the same use case. That's why it is so important to *describe* the problem and the solution. There is nothing wrong with your code but consider someone looking at this question from a Google search: they don't have a clue what the real problem is and the change you made is subtle (and not even marked with a comment). Even if they see you added a `&` they won't necessarily know why, or what the effect is, or what the alternatives are.

Answer (score 0):

OK so as I edited my original question, here is a solution for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string expression{ "(###((##)#)(#(#)#)#(#))" };

int countHash(std::string::iterator& stringIterator, std::string::iterator stringEnd)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (stringIterator != stringEnd)
    {
        if (*stringIterator == '#')
        {
            result += 1;
        }
        else if (*stringIterator == '(')
        {
            result += countHash(++stringIterator, stringEnd);
            continue;
        }
        else if (*stringIterator == ')')
        {
            ++stringIterator;
            return result;
        }
        ++stringIterator;
    }
    return result;
}

int countHash(std::string expression)
{
    auto it = expression.begin();
    return countHash(it, expression.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << countHash(expression) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output: 11**

So one important thing was that you need to pass the string by reference to avoid processing the same segments of the string multiple times after you return from your recursive calls.

What I also had difficulty with is that you need to do a `continue` after the recursive call in my `while` loop. This is because you don't want to increment `stringIterator` after your return from the recursive call. 
You could also do this with the post increment operator and with a `switch-case` as @bruno did it in his answer. That was the insight for me. If you are not only checking for characters `switch-case` is not possible though. You could use a do-while loop but I don't like that.

On more important thing was that you need to increment your iterator before returning from the `)` branch. That is because that's the end of an expression and if it was a recursive call you want to go on with the expression on the caller side.

One other problem was that you cant pass `expression.begin()` if your function takes a reference to iterator.

For the

```
std::string expr = "(+1 (+22 3 25) 5 (+44 (*3 2)))";
```

expression my solution is available at https://github.com/bencemeszaroshu/expeval/blob/master/expeval/expeval.cpp. I don't like it as it is now but I will try to improve it later. (Happy to hear suggestions.) It is working however. Thanks everyone for your help, I'm marking @bruno answer as accepted because it helped me the most.